# Angular: Prevent navigating to non-existing id parameter

Tags: angular, routes

What is a correct way to prevent manually routing to a non-existent parameter in the url, when we have the path as in the example: 'edit/:id', where id is the parameter? Of course, it works correctly if we enter an id which matches an existing url, but does not work if we input a non-existent id

I have tried using the wildcard route, but that works only for the full route, without the parameter. Even if you enter some gibberish after /user/ as a paramter, angular still considers it as a valid route.

These are the current routes:

```
{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'user',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'user',
        component: UserComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'user/:id',
        component: UserEditComponent,
    }
}
```

Comment: One way would be to use angular guard to check for a valid and stop navigation if id is invalid.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Route Resolver. This way you can first resolve the getSomethingById, and if it fails do what you want to do. Note in the example code I use 'of, Observable' from RxJS and catchError from Rxjs/operators.

```
@Injectable()
export class GetSingleItemResolver implements Resolve<any>{
      constructor(private apiService: APIService) {}

      resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        return this.apiService.getItemById(route.params['id']).pipe(
          catchError(err => {
            //Do what you want to do in the case that there is no item found with the ID

            return of(null)
          });
        );
      }
}
```

Do not forget to add the resolver to your module under the providers array.
In your routing module you need to add it like this:

```
  { 
    path: 'detailPage/:id',
    component: someDetailComponent,
    resolve: {
      singleItem: GetSingleItemResolver
    }
  }
```

If you work lik this, you can get the singleItem from the router, so you dont have to make the getItemById request in the component itself. This will already be resolved by your resolver. You can get the item from the router like this:

```
this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
  this.singleItem = data['singleItem'];
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: An elegant solution, but the problem is that I am getting the data from a backend database, not from a service or server, so I don't think there is a way to implement the same logic for this scenario, since I cannot pass the data as observables and subscribe to it.

Comment: In the component where you want to use the singleItem, you make a get request to get the item or user or whatever correct? The code you use to get the item by id should go instead of this part: this.apiService.getItemById(route.params['id']).  This will get your item, if there is one, if not, you go into the pipe with the catchError. The rest of the code is generic and not related to the rest of your code

Comment: If you do not make any request to get your single User (what would be a bit strange in itself), then you can still use the Resolver to resolve something before you navigate to the new route. You can make a check for your user the way you want yourself. If there is a users return the user, if there is no user, you can copy the catchError part of the example above.

Comment: I understand, the problem is that I am not using observables so I cannot use the function provided by rxjs to operate with observables.

Comment: You don't have to use an observable, the resolve you create is an observable and the other RxJS functions (of and catchError) you can import and use on the resolve observable like in my example. If you get your user with an observable is not important.  Here is a more simple example without the RxJS stuff: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-resolve/